# Buildout installs django but can't import

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, buildout

Here's my buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    django

[versions]
djangorecipe = 1.5
django = 1.7

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = timetable
eggs =
```

Here's my routine for setting up project in a new environment:

```
virtualenv .
source bin/activate
easy_install -U setuptools
python bootstrap.py
bin/buildout -v
python manage.py migrate
```

When I run bin/buildout, it says django is installed, and django binary is in the bin folder. But when I run manage.py, it can't import django:

```
(timetable)mick88@s59gr2dmmd:~/timetable$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

But it works when I install django using pip. Why doesn't buildout install django in my virualenv? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buildout doesn't install anything in a virtualenv. Buildout collects python packages and adds programs to the `bin/` directory that have the correct python packages added to their `sys.path`.

So:

- virtualenv/pip installs *everything* into the virtualenv. You have to activate the virtualenv so that it can modify your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (and the `PATH` variable). This way the python from your virtualenv's `bin/` directory is used and the python packages from the `lib/` dir.
- Buildout adds the necessary "pythonpath" changes to scripts in `bin/`, modifying the `sys.path` setting directly instead of through the environment variable.

The **one thing** you need to know is that you should run `bin/django` instead of `python manage.py`. The effect is the same, only `bin/django` already has the right `sys.path` setting.

As an example, just look at the contents of the `bin/django` script. It should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
  '/vagrant',
  '/vagrant/eggs/djangorecipe-1.10-py2.7.egg',
  '/vagrant/eggs/Django-1.6.6-py2.7.egg',
  '/vagrant/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
  '/vagrant/eggs/zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg',
  '/vagrant/eggs/South-1.0-py2.7.egg',
  ...
  ]

import djangorecipe.manage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(djangorecipe.manage.main('yoursite.settings'))
```